# Using BeautifulSoup, Can I quickly traverse to a specific parent element?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Say I reference an element inside of a table in a HTML page like this:

```
someEl = soup.findAll(text = "some text")
```

I know for sure this element is embedded inside a table, is there a way to find the parent table without having to call .parent so many times?

```
<table...>

..
..
<tr>....<td><center><font..><b>some text</b></font></center></td>....<tr>

<table>
```

Answer (score 6):

Check out `findParents`, it has a similar form to `findAll`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup("<table>...</table>")

for text in soup.findAll(text='some text')
  table = text.findParents('table')[0]
  # table is your now your most recent `<table>` parent
```

Here are [the docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#findAllPrevious%28name,%20attrs,%20text,%20limit,%20**kwargs%29%20and%20findPrevious%28name,%20attrs,%20text,%20**kwargs%29) for `findAllPrevious` and also `findParents`.

Answer (score 1):

```
while someEl.name != "table":
    someEl = someEl.parent
# someEl is now the table
```